# ios DemoCast Player Chromecast "does not support app"

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

After getting my chromcast whitelisted and receiving Application ID. I downloaded the DemoCastPlayer from github & the ios SDK. The following are the steps i did to setup and run the application

```
   1) set up the ios project with the cast framework,
      changed [YOUR_APP_NAME]  with google supplied app ID
   2) In the app bundle Root.plist changed Default Value to point to 
      http://mywebiste.com/cc/rcvr/media.xml
   3) I uploaded the example receiver.html with the app ID & medial.xml to my website 
       https://mywebiste.com/rcvr/receiver.html 


  Unfortunately Im getting the following Error white Discovering the Devices :

   scanStarted

   -[GCKNetworkRequest performHTTPGet:timeout:]  started GET request 
    for: http://192.168.1.101:8008/ssdp/device-desc.xml

   -[GCKNetworkRequest httpRequest:didCompleteWithStatusCode:finalURL:headers:data:]  
     httpRequest:didCompleteWithStatusCode:200:data:1082 bytes

   -[GCKNetworkRequest performHTTPGet:timeout:]  
     started GET request for: http://192.168.1.101:8008/apps/%5B7a479924-b922-41a0-ae85-05b27a9582b1%5D

   -[GCKNetworkRequest httpRequest:didCompleteWithStatusCode:finalURL:headers:data:] 
    httpRequest:didCompleteWithStatusCode:404:data:0 bytes

   **-[GCKApplicationSupportFilterListener networkRequest:didFailWithError:] 
     Device <0x1fda9d70:GCKDevice> Chromecast0704 (64cb88c8-9617-8099-8d1c-8218b784ae25)
     does not support app [7a479924-b922-41a0-ae85-xxxxxxxxxxxx]**

  I doubled checked that both my receiver.html file and ios application have the same ID 
   and the send chromcast serial number to google is set . 

  Any Idea how to solve that issue ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra "[" and "]" around your appId, please remove them from everywhere, including from your receiver file and try again.

Comment: What an oversight , But really appreciate you help Mr Ali.